# How to close existing connections to the database programmatically before dropping it?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I sometimes get errors when I try to drop a database programmatically that is in use. So I use the wizard to delete the database that has a checkbox that says "Close existing connections" to successfully delete it. Now I want to do this using sql codes if ever.

`IF EXISTS(select 1 from sys.databases where name = 'Time Monitoring1001')
    DROP DATABASE [Time Monitoring1001]`

Answer (score 0):

This would do it.This should disconnect everyone else but you

```
use master
alter database YourDbName set single_user with rollback immediate
```

EDIT : You could also try setting it offline

```
alter database YourDbName set offline with rollback immediate
```

Comment: isn't it not dropping because someone is using the database INCLUDING me?? and when I use that line, it's still not dropping and same error shows.

Comment: Now that I executed that code, I can't even delete it even checking the "Close existing connections" checkbox in the wizard. lol
So I have to revert it by setting it to MULTI_USER again

Comment: make sure u are using the master instance

Comment: something happens if I recreate same database with same name

Cannot create file'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Time Monitoring1001.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.